# How to change Build directory dynamically in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I'm stuck with a problem I want to create each days build in different folders means if the build is created on 17/5/2013 I want the build in a folder named 17/05/2013 and so on How can I achieve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MSBUILD 4 you can use [Property Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx#BKMK_GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove) to construct a custom output folder.

In C# this would generate the folder name:

```
System.DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Using that same logic in MSBUILD

```
<Target Name="DateStampTest">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputRoot>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)</OutputRoot>
        <DateTimeStamp>$([System.DateTime]::Today.ToString("yyyy.dd.MM"))</DateTimeStamp>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>

    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="Override the output folder with: '$(OutputRoot)$(DateTimeStamp)'" />
</Target>
```

Saved this to a project file in "C:\Test\" and running msbuild  /t:DateStampTest gives us the following output:

1>Project "C:\Test\" on node 1 (target1 target(s)).

1>Target1:

Override the output folder with: 'C:\Test\2013.17.05'

1>Done Building Project "C:\Test\" (target1 target(s)).